# How prevent to create a .exe.config in a Windows Forms Application build (Visual Studio Community 2019 - C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, build

I'm working in a legacy project (Windows Forms Application), with target framework .NET 2.0. The goal is to build a single `.exe` file that does not depend in any configuration file (in particular that does not depend on the `.exe.config` because the application doesn't need anything from this configuration file).

The characteristics of the project:

```
Application:
Targe framework: .NET Framework 2.0
Output type: Windows Application
Auto-generate binding redirecs: Not enabled

Build:
Platform target: Any CPU

Visual Studio Community 2019, version 16.1.3
```

The solution has a `app.config` file that I've tried to remove but for some reason It ***seems*** that remains in the project. When I say ***seems*** to remains in the project is because I follow this steps:

1. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the `App.config`, and then click on **Exclude From Project**.
2. Rebuild the project, and still the `.exe.config` in generated.
3. Again in the Solution Explorer > Add > New Item, and when I try to add an Application Configuration File with the name `App.config` VS show this message: **A file with the name 'App.config' already exists. Do you want to replace it?**.

(I've also tried with the right-click on the `App.config`, and then click **Delete** option)

This seems to indicate that the configuration file is not effectively removed from the project, and therefore the `.exe.config` is still generated.

Also, I've checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289509/how-to-not-copy-app-config-file-to-output-directory/40293508#40293508), and tried changing the files properties (**Build Action**, **Copy to Output Directory**, etc) but the `.exe.config` file remains in the build.

Finally, I've tried (probably more as a desperate attempt) with uncheck the **Auto-generate binding redirects** which prevents the generation of the `.exe.config` but the `.exe` is not running properly.

Just as an additional information, the content of the `.exe.config` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Company.Afis.ImageContainer" publicKeyToken="97cac07b8409e999" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.1827" newVersion="2.5.0.1827" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Other post that I've checked:

- [How to make work 'do not copy' app.config to output directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949968/how-to-make-work-do-not-copy-app-config-to-output-directory)
- [appname.exe.config not created on windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859969/appname-exe-config-not-created-on-windows-application?rq=1)
- [Release build without config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245139/release-build-without-config-file/36245299#36245299)
- [How to not copy app.config file to output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289509/how-to-not-copy-app-config-file-to-output-directory/40293508#40293508)

If any other information is needed, please let me know to update it.

Comment: You can disable assembly bindings and use [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: How about pdb-files? Do you have them disabled? I am asking because I am not sure why do you want to disable exe.config-files. To have *clean* `Bin` folder with just one exe inside? Does other files cause problem? Which problem?

Comment: @Reza Aghaei I'm checking that, thanks. @Sinatr, I've enable/disable Debug info, but it does not affect the `.exe.config`. And the Idea is to have a `.exe` file that does not depend on any other file, so yes.. to have a clean `Bin` folder. As far as problems, well if I delete the `.exe.config` file the `.exe` is not running properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable auto generation of assembly binding redirects and instead, handle  [`AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event of the current [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.currentdomain?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and load the requested assembly in the event handler.

- **Disable Auto-generate assembly binding redirects**

  Right click on project, choose *Properties* and in the project properties page, in the first tab (*Application* tab), uncheck *Auto-generate binding redirects*. You can do the same by editing project file and setting `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>false</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>`.

- **Handle AssemblyResolve Event**

  You should add the event handler before the run-time tries to load the assembly. For example, in the static constructor of `Program` class. For example, in the following code, I suppose the application is looking for `MyAssembly` which I have it as `MyAssembly2.dll` in application's folder.

  ```
  static Program()
  {
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
  }
  private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, 
      ResolveEventArgs args)
  {
      if (new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name == "MyAssembly")
          return Assembly.LoadFrom(
              Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "MyAssembly2.dll"));
      throw new Exception();
  }
  ```